# Find the Presence of Configuration File

Tags: php

If the `Configuration.php` is found, it should require the file. If not it should throw an error.

Here is my Code :

```
if (is_file($path."configuration.php")) {
    is_file("install/index.php") ? header("location:install/index.php") : print('Failed locating configuration file <br/> Failed locating installation directory <br/> Please execute installation script manually <br/>');
    exit;
} else {

    require_once "configuration.php";
}
```

But I am not seeing any error or output. How can I make my code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you should use  `!_isfile` to check the presense.

```
if (!is_file($path."configuration.php")) { 
..
}
```

And once the file found. You have missed the `$path` in your file require.

```
require_once $path."configuration.php";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (is_file($path."configuration.php")) {
    is_file("install/index.php") ? header("location:install/index.php") : print('Failed locating configuration file <br/> Failed locating installation directory <br/> Please execute installation script manually <br/>');
    exit;
} else {

    require_once $path."configuration.php";
}
```

Comment: I have missed the **(!is_file)** too